# Express $w = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$ in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Express $w = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$ in polar coordinates.

However $u$ is nowhere defined. Do you know what could be meant by that?

Comment: Just a guess: suppose you have a function $u(x,y)$. Then define a new function $f(r,\theta)=u(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)$. Then maybe express the quantity above in terms of partial derivatives involving just $f,r,\theta$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132039/265466 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1877245/265466